# Why does my JavaScript function add extra space at the beginning when taking input as a comma-separated string?

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

Why this function takes extra space in front while taking an input?

**My html.erb file is:**

```
<%= form.text_field :monthly_income, class: 'form-control', required: true, onkeyup: "formatLoanAmount(this)" %>
```

**And my script file is:**

```
function formatLoanAmount(element) {
        const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'bdt',
            minimumFractionDigits: 0,
            maximumFractionDigits: 0,
        });
        input_value = element.value.toString().replace(/BDT/g, '').replace(/,/g, '');
        formatted_number = formatter.format(input_value);
        formatted_number = formatted_number.toString().replace(/BDT/g, '');
        element.value = formatted_number;
    }
```

I'm tryig to take input as a comma sepetated string and expection an integer as output.

Comment: try to add trim() input_value = input_value.replace(/,/g, '').trim();

Answer (score 1):

However, you can use trim() function to remove whitespaces if exits. Here is the updated version of your code.

```
function formatLoanAmount(element) {
    const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'bdt',
        minimumFractionDigits: 0,
        maximumFractionDigits: 0,
    });
    input_value = element.value.toString().replace(/BDT/g, '');
    input_value = input_value.replace(/,/g, '').trim(); // Replace commas and trim whitespace if any
    formatted_number = formatter.format(input_value);
    formatted_number = formatted_number.replace(/BDT/g, '').trim();
    element.value = formatted_number;
}
```

Comment: _"this approach will also remove any whitespace that follows a comma"_... nope ~ https://jsfiddle.net/4cmu63Ly/

Comment: @Phil Apologies for the confusion in my previous response. You are correct, using replace(/,/g, '') will only remove the commas from the input value without affecting any whitespace.  Response updated after your suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

The extra space in front of the input value might be caused by the `replace` method in your `formatLoanAmount` function. Specifically, the `replace(/BDT/g, '')` part of the code is removing all occurrences of the string "BDT" from the input value. If the input value starts with "BDT", then this will leave an extra space at the beginning of the formatted number.

To fix this issue, you can modify the `replace` method to remove all occurrences of "BDT " (with a space after "BDT") instead of just "BDT". Here's the updated code:

```js
function formatLoanAmount(element) {
  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'bdt',
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
  });
  input_value = element.value.toString().replace(/BDT /g, '').replace(/,/g, '');
  formatted_number = formatter.format(input_value);
  formatted_number = formatted_number.toString().replace(/BDT/g, '');
  element.value = formatted_number;
}
```

This should remove any extra spaces at the beginning of the formatted number.

Additionally, if you want to convert the formatted number back to an integer without commas, you can modify the `formatted_number` variable to remove all commas before assigning it to `element.value`. Here's the updated code:

```js
function formatLoanAmount(element) {
  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'bdt',
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
  });
  input_value = element.value.toString().replace(/BDT /g, '').replace(/,/g, '');
  formatted_number = formatter.format(input_value);
  formatted_number = formatted_number.toString().replace(/BDT/g, '').replace(/,/g, '');
  element.value = formatted_number;
}
```

This should ensure that the input value is converted to an integer without commas after formatting.